# how to check if a value exists in a sql table using c# and if yes to proceed with if

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to check username against specific column in SQL table and if it doesnt exist bring a message and if exists - proceed with a code. But for some reason even when user exists I can see blocking message only. Could you help me to identify an error?

```
        private void btnGrntOvw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string User =        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        string queryString = ("SELECT COUNT([Guarantee]) FROM [tablename] 
        WHERE [Guarantee] = '" + User + "'");
        string connString = @"Data Source=etc";
        string groupId = textGrntOvw.Text.Trim();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var userCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());

                if (userCount == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The report is locked because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to run the report.");
                }

                else if (groupId.Length < 6 | groupId.Length > 13)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect customer ID");
                }

                else if (radioGrntOvwSingle.Checked)
                {

                    GrntOvw frm1 = new GrntOvw(groupId);
                    frm1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                    frm1.Show(this);

                }

                else if (radioGrntOvwGroup.Checked)
                {
                    GrntOvwGroup frm3 = new GrntOvwGroup(groupId);
                    frm3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                    frm3.Show(this);
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select one of the options");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I expect that if user exists to proceed and check whether groupID has proper length etc, but if it doesnt I need only first message to be shown

Comment: use parameters, save yourself from sql injection

Comment: You should just stick a breakpoint in and step through. Is User populated correctly, does the SQL command produce a result if you put the User in, what value does userCount end up as, are you testing manually in SSMS or similar against the same connection string you're using in the code, etc much of this can be debugged in seconds by you

Comment: I see no bugs either. Step through the method, pay attention to the connection properties. In a similar situation i was connecting to a wrong database.

Answer (score 1):

I would first run the raw SQL against the database to see if it brings back the expected result with the Username. I would also recommend using SQL parameters as shown below to prevent SQL injection:

```
 // 1. declare command object with parameter
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([Guarantee]) FROM [tablename] 
        WHERE [Guarantee] = @Guarantee", conn);

   // 2. define parameters used in command object
    SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@Guarantee";
    param.Value         = User;

   // 3. add new parameter to command object
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

//Execute your code
```

Comment: Thanks, added parameters but it doesnt help. SQL brings expected result indeed

Comment: That's puzzling. I would recommend debugging line by line to see how it ends up blocking.